# STL: Set of natural numbers from A to B

Tags: c++, stl, performance

I want to add natural numbers from A to B in a set. Currently I am inserting each and every number from A to B, one by one in the set like this,

```
set<int> s;
for(int j=A; j<=B; j++)
    s.insert(j);
```

But it takes `O(n)` time (here `n = (B - A)+1`). Is there any pre-defined way in STL to do it in `O(1)` time?

Thanks

Comment: STL is not magic. If you need k numbers in a set, you need O(k) operations. If you want to change your representation (e.g interval), that is a different matter.

Comment: Perfect job for an immutable container. Unfortunately C++ standard doesn't have concept like that. And constness is sole but poor surrogate...

Answer (score 3):

Allocating memory to hold n number is always going to be in at least O(n) so I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Nitpick: Allocating memory to hold n numbers could be O(1). It is _filling_ that memory that takes O(n) time.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that is true.  O(n) with calloc, though

Comment: (Also, use Omega(n) instead of O(n), and yes, I fell into that trap myself :-))

Answer (score 2):

No. The shortest amount of time it takes to fill a container with sequential values is `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 2):

Technically I believe this is `O(n log n)` because the `set.insert` function is `log n`.  `O(n)` is the best you can do I think but for that you would need to use an unsorted container like a `vector` or `list`.

Comment: the set container is the implementation of red-black tree

Answer (score 2):

With the STL set container you will never get O(1) time. You may be able to reduce the running time by using the `set(InputIterator f, InputIterator l, const key_compare& comp)` constructor and passing in a custom iterator that iterates over the given integer range. The reason this may run faster (depends on stl implementation, compiler, etc) is that you are reducing the call stack depth. In your snippet, you go all the way down from your .insert() call to the actual insertion and back for each integer. Using the alternate constructor, your increment operation is moved down into the frame in which the insertion is performed. The increment operation would now have the possible overhead of a function call if your compiler can't inline it. You should benchmark this before taking this approach though. It may be slower if your stl implementation has a shallow call stack for .insert().

In general though, if you need a set of a contiguous range of integers, you could see massive performance gains by implementing a specialized set class that can store and compare only the upper and lower bounds of each set.

Comment: ++ for the second paragraph. KISS.

Answer (score 0):

`O(1)` is only true for default constructor.
`O(n)` for the copy constructors and sorted sequence insertion using iterators.
`O(log n!)` for unsorted sequence insertion using iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to complately out of the box, you could design a "lazy-loaded" array, custom to this task.  Basically, upon access, if the value had not been previously set, it would determine the correct value.

This would allow the setup to be O(1) (assuming inintialize the "not previously set" flags is itself O(1)), but wouldn't speed up the overall operation -- it would just scatter that time over the rest of the run (It would probably take longer overall).